# Response.End Before Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I have two aspx pages: MakeAppointment.aspx and AcceptOutlook.aspx. The MakeAppointment collects contact info and appointment time and location and then response.direct to AcceptOutlook to output an .ICS file with all the info collected from the MakeAppointment page. The issue I am facing is .ICS (outlook file) is showing up but it is at the MakeAppointment page and it is not redirecting to AcceptOutlook. Here is my code for both pages. I want the outlook file to show up in the AcceptOutlook page and that is where it is creating the outlook file.

MakeAppointment.aspx.cs

```
Response.Redirect("AcceptOutlook.aspx?Endtime=" + EndTime + "&pkHCSACase=" + pkHCSACase);
```

AcceptOutlook.aspx.cs

```
sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("PRODID:-//ICSTestCS/");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");

        // Define the event.
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        sbICSFile.Append("DTSTART;TZID=US/Pacific:");

        //start date time
        sbICSFile.Append(startdate);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("T" + StartTime);
        //end date time
        sbICSFile.Append("DTEND;TZID=US/Pacific:");
        sbICSFile.Append(startdate);
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("T" + EndTime);


        sbICSFile.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + Thisrow.AppointmentContactName + " " + Programs); //Contact name and list of programs
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + Thisrow.CaseNotes); //Body is notes
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + Thisrow.AppointmentContactPhone); //Location is phone number
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("CATEGORIES:Monica"); //color code
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("UID:1");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");

        sbICSFile.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:" + Hitemail);

        sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");


        Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=CalendarEvent1.ics");
        Response.Write(sbICSFile);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: It is either or. Either you have a visual page or you have an attachment and a prompt to save it. I believe you expect to have both, which is unfortunately not possible. In your case, the page is "rendered" as an attachment, what browser displays then in a window is the very previous page, your first one.

Comment: In addition to what @WiktorZychla said, To make it more presentable you can show the details on AcceptOutlook page in read-only form with confirm button which will then download the ICS file